# Как обратиться к view в андроид?

Tags: android, kotlin

Использую последнюю версию Android Studio 2020.3.1 Patch 1 (Windows 10 64x, 16gb). Делаю один проект по примеру.

1. В разметке у меня есть `NavigationView` с id `nav_view`
2. Мой `builde.gradle` выглядит так:

   ```
   dependencies {
       implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
       implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
       implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
       implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
   }
   ```

Когда я пишу код в `MainActivity`, то у меня выходит красным цветом `nav_view`:

```kotlin
nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
```

В какую сторону смотреть?

Answer (score 4):

Добро пожаловать в мир разработки под Андроид. Чтобы достать view по id, используйте метод `findViewById`:

```kotlin
val navigationView = findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)
```

Далее, можете пользоваться полученным `navigationView`:

```kotlin
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
```

Возможно, что в примере, по которому вы делаете проект, использовался kotlin-synthetic. Но эта штука уже [устарела](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration), вместо нее теперь можно использовать [view-binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding).

Как только вы наберетесь опыта и вам надоест каждый раз писать `findViewById`, то посмотрите в сторону использования [view-binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding).

Comment: Vadik Большое спасибо. Куда нажать на плюсик :) ?

Comment: Чтобы отметить правильный ответ, нужно нажать слева на [галочку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) напротив ответа.